# Are there other options for DocBook support in Maven besides Doxia and docbkx-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, docbook

I'm looking for possibilities for generating documentation using DocBook as part of my Maven build process. What I'm finding is everyone is suggesting [docbkx-maven-plugin](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net) over Doxia. The problem is that it seems docbkx is no longer maintained or at least they've moved and left no forwarding address for where to look at the source code. According to the plugin's website the repository is on googlecode.com which of course hasn't existed for many years now. The last update I found of the plugin was back in 2016. This leads me to believe that the plugin is no longer maintained. Does anyone have any news to the contrary, or a different option for generating DocBook output during a maven build?

Comment: Why not taking a look to Asciidoctor?

Answer (score 1):

The source is available here: https://github.com/mimil/docbkx-tools

It does look like the project is no longer maintained, having seen no commits since 2015.

You don't need the plugin. If you have a working DocBook toolchain, you can use Maven to invoke it. The plugin could make certain aspects easier.

Comment: Sorry, but from the project's own configuration page and the plugin dependency list (which includes FOP) I'm not certain why you mentioned it only supports / supported HTML output.  I've used the plugin in the past to generate PDFs, among other things.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure where I got the idea that the plugin was HTML-only. I cannot find that reference, so I've updated my answer.